# Conteo de palabras con javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer un contador de palabras de un textarea pero solo logro contar los carácteres no las palabras, ¿me podrían ayudar?

Html:

```
<div>
   <h3>Contador</h3>
   <textarea rows="10" id="texto"></textarea>
   <button onclick="contar()">Contar</button>
   <input type="text" id="num" style="width:100px;">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
var num   = document.getElementById("num");

function contar(){
    var text  = texto.value.length;
    num.value = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te funciona porque estás obteniendo la longitud del valor del text area (todo en conjunto). Si quieres obtener las palabras debes separar todo el contenido del texto area por espacios. Para ello puedes usar [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) y usar `' '` como separador, eso te devolverá un array con el total de palabras. Luego para saber cuántas existen usas `length` y estableces ese valor en tu input.

```js
  var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
var num   = document.getElementById("num");

function contar() {
  var words  = texto.value.split(' ');
  num.value = words.length;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h3>Contador</h3>
   <textarea rows="10" id="texto"></textarea>
   <button onclick="contar()">Contar</button>
   <input type="text" id="num" style="width:100px;">
</div>
```